# Fix or start over in ASP.NET Entity Framework - IdentityModel Migrations and Database messed up

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

In an attempt to modify the built-in IdentityModel with a new `balance` attribute in ASP.NET MVC applications. I ended up breaking the Database and/or migrations of this model in a way I don't even know how to return to a previous state.

So far I tried to clear everything up by deleting the database, the migrations and removing the new attribute from the model code. This is what I did:

1. Delete the database in the Server Explorer.
2. Delete the Migrations folder.
3. Revert the code changes in the `IdentityModel` class. The code:

   ```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
   {
       public ApplicationUser()
       {
           //balance = 0;
       }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string surname { get; set; }
       public string company { get; set; }
       //public int balance { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Try `update-database` in the terminal. It will fail and ask to enable migrations first.
5. `Enable migrations`.
6. Try `update-database` in the terminal. It will fail and state the model has changed but no migration has been added.
7. `add-migration postclear`. The code:

   ```
   public partial class postclear : DbMigration
   {
       public override void Up()
       {
           DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "balance");
       }

       public override void Down()
       {
           AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "balance", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
       }
   }
   ```
8. `update-database` again and I got this error

   > Error Number: 4924, State: 1, Class: 16
   >   `ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN` failed because column 'balance' does not exist in table 'AspNetUsers'.

How can I fix my database and migrations? Which is the correct way of changing `IdentityModel` and migrate the changes to the database?

Comment: Try commenting out the `DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "balance");` and run `update-database` again. If it works, you can uncomment it for the next update.

Comment: You could also create a new initial migration with ignorechanges set. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1

Comment: I got it working with the first solution. When I tried again to uncomment my `balance` attribute in the model and add a migration for it, it worked as well. I think I am on the right track now (fingers crossed though, I don't yet understand code-first migrations so well)

Comment: @CoOl suggestion worked for me. thx